# INSERT INTO TABLE query gives no response inside nodejs Lambda function

Tags: node.js, oracle, api, aws-lambda, node-oracledb

I'm using lambda functions to do my database operations. When i perform GET from my client side, SELECT statements work fine meaning it can connect and retrieve data. However, I cant get this insert statement to work.

My code:

```js
try {
  conn = await oracledb.getConnection(connAttr);

  console.log('Connected to database');

  let result = await conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO product (NAME, DISCOUNT, DATE_VALID_FROM, DATE_VALID_TO) VALUES (:NAME, :DISCOUNT, TO_DATE(:DATE_VALID_FROM, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE(:DATE_VALID_TO, 'DD-MM-YYYY'))",
    {
      NAME: requestBody.Name,
      DISCOUNT: requestBody.Disc,
      DATE_VALID_FROM: requestBody.StartDate,
      DATE_VALID_TO: requestBody.EndDate,
    },
    function (err, result) {
      const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(result),
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
          'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
      };
      callback(null, response);
      if (err) {
        console.log('error is here');
      }
    }
  );
} catch (err) {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 400,
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: err }),
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
  };
}
```

when i call this from the client side form I get `Http Error 502` and when I view in cloudwatch logs I can see `'Connected to database' and then 'error is here'` which means the query is never executed successfully.

I'm using a lambda layer with the package oracledb-prebuilt-for-lambda which is basically node-oracledb.

When i console log requestbody i can see the parameters I passed to the lambda.

I have a POST method with proxy lambda integration to this lambda and CORS is enabled as well.

It seems that only the query that is not working.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How does it _not work_? Do you get any errors reported? Why aren't you logging the `err` value?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing async/await and callback styles of programming. Just use async/await. For example your call to the SQL statement should simply be:

```
  let result = await conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO product (NAME, DISCOUNT, DATE_VALID_FROM, DATE_VALID_TO) VALUES (:NAME, :DISCOUNT, TO_DATE(:DATE_VALID_FROM, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE(:DATE_VALID_TO, 'DD-MM-YYYY'))",
    {
      NAME: requestBody.Name,
      DISCOUNT: requestBody.Disc,
      DATE_VALID_FROM: requestBody.StartDate,
      DATE_VALID_TO: requestBody.EndDate,
    })
```

After that you do result handling